# How to declare symbols (such as @) in strings in arff file?

Tags: java, weka, arff

I have a question that I am really confused about and I am sorry if that is so stupid. 
I have been using so far only numeric data to achieve sentiment analysis in Java that I obtain by using only Python libraries but now I realize that I am forced to use Java to preprocess my data as a text from the beginning.

I want to use the StringToWord of Weka to tokenize my data and then apply pre-processings plus tfidf. 
My question is, how do I need to handle with symbols in string in an arff file ? Because when I just define the attributes as below I get the "nominal value not declared in header, read Token[@Microsoft].." for the first line in my data.

```
@relation corpus 
@attribute id numeric
@attribute text string
@attribute label {positive,neutral,negative}
@attribute label2 {neutral,non-neutral}
@data
628949369883000000  dear @Microsoft the...  negative    non-neutral
```

I also tried representing my data as follow with commas. I get the same error.

```
628949369883000000,dear @Microsoft the...,negative,non-neutral
```

So how should I declare then this string which includes symbols ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I just had to give my string in quotes.

```
@relation file 
@attribute id numeric
@attribute tweet string
@attribute label {positive,neutral,negative}
@attribute label2 {neutral,non-neutral}

@data
628949369883000000,"dear@ Microsoft .... C'mon.",negative,non-neutral
```